# How to pass props to Bootstrap OverlayTrigger overlay component?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-forwardref

I created a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-rgb-vks06?file=/src/App.js

I am trying to pass props to the SlotSettings component, but I get this error:

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access
>   this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

I tried to read both Bootstrap docs and React docs but I could not understand how this should work.
This is the code I'm using:

```
  const SlotSettings = props => {
    console.log(props.hello); // this works
    return <Popover {...props} id="popover-basic">
      <Popover.Title as="h3">Popover right</Popover.Title>
      <Popover.Content>
        And here's some <strong>amazing</strong> content. It's very engaging.
        right?
      </Popover.Content>
    </Popover>
  }

  const getDaySlots = slots => {
    if (slots.length >= 1) {
      return slots.map(slot => {
        const variant = slot.status === "free" ? "success" : "secondary";

        const buttonRef = createRef();
        return (
          <OverlayTrigger
            key={uuid()}
            trigger="click"
            placement="bottom"
            overlay={<SlotSettings hello="hello" />}
            rootClose
          >
            <Button size="sm" ref={buttonRef} variant={variant} style={{ margin: "8px"}}>{slot.start}</Button>
          </OverlayTrigger>
        )
      });  
    }
    return "No lessons available."
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I accomplished this by utilizing the `popperConfig` property of `OverlayTrigger`. 
PopperConfig is used to pass and object to the the underlying popper instance.
[link to docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#overlay-trigger-props)

Simple example:

```
function renderTooltip(props) {
    let message = ""

    //Sometimes, props.popper.state is undefined. 
    //It runs this function enough times that state gets a value 
    if (props.popper.state) {
        message = props.popper.state.options.testObj
    }

    return (
        <Tooltip id="button-tooltip" {...props}>
            {message}
        </Tooltip>
    );
}

function getDaySlots(slots) {
    //Other stuff
    return (
        <OverlayTrigger
            placement="right"
            delay={{ show: 250, hide: 400 }}
            overlay={renderTooltip}
            popperConfig={{testObj:"hello there"}}
        >
            <Button variant="success">Click here</Button>
        </OverlayTrigger >
    );
}
```

I messed with your codesandbox, but couldn't get `popper` to get a `state` value for some reason. What I posted above works for my project, hope this helps you get started.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState  ,useRef} from 'react';
import {  Popover, Overlay } from 'react-bootstrap';
const DemoComponent = () => {
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
const target = useRef(null);
 return (
 <div className="">
  <span ref={target} onMouseEnter={() => setShow(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setShow(false)}>
    open tooltip
  </span>
  <Overlay target={target.current} show={show} placement="top">
    {(props) => (
      <Popover id="popover-basic" className="customize-tooltip"  {...props}>

        <Popover.Body>
          put here dyanamic content
        </Popover.Body>
      </Popover>
    )}
  </Overlay>
</div>
  );}

export default DemoComponent;
```

Comment: Please add further information

Comment: This answer would be better with some explanation. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your custom popover in React.forwardRef, this way you get access to ref which you pass over to Popover:

```
const CustomPopover = forwardRef(
  ({ customProp, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <Popover ref={ref} {...props}>
        <Popover.Header as="h3">{customProp}</Popover.Header>
        <Popover.Body>
          And here's some <strong>amazing</strong> content. It's very engaging.
      right?
        </Popover.Body>
      </Popover>
    );
  }
);
```

Then just use OverlayTrigger with your custom popover component in overlay prop as usual:

```
<OverlayTrigger
  trigger="hover"
  placement="auto"
  overlay={<CustomPopover customProp={'custom value'} />}
>
  <button>hover me</button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```